# Как динамически унаследовать тип от типа typescript

Tags: typescript, типы

У меня есть тип **TODO**

```
type TODO = {
  id: number,
  ...
}
```

И есть функция, которая удаляет **TODO** (принимая `todo.id`)

```
const removeTodo = (todoID: number) => {...}
```

Но я хочу как-то связать `todo.id` с типом TODO. Чтобы, когда я изменил TODO на это:

```
type TODO = {
  id: string,
  ...
}
```

функция `removeTodo` тоже ожидала именно `string`, а не `number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить вот такой вариант:

```
type TODOID = number;

type TODO = {
  id: TODOID
}

function todo(id: TODOID) {
  return id;
}
```

Или вот так

```
type TODO = {
  id: number
}

function todo(id: TODO['id']) {
  return id;
}
```